Where can I find a proof of the Levi Decomposition Theorem for reductive Lie algebras
Recently in a course of Lie algebra we saw the Levi decomposition theorem and the professor mentioned that this result can be also used and proved for reductive Lie algebras.
Specifically he mentioned that the theorem is proven by using the
complete reducibility of finite-dimensional representations of semisimple Lie algebras. I am curious to see the proof of this result and I have been searching for it but I have been unable to do it, so if someone knows where to find it, I would be really greatfull.

The Levi decomposition can be proved in general (characteristic zero), not only for reductive Lie algebras. I suppose that (almost) all books on Lie algebras have a proof. See also here, section $2.4$.

I would think that, for example, Varadarajan's book on Lie groups and algebras would prove this. It should be in all reasonable textbooks. And, probably, in many peoples' on-line notes, by this year. :)
